# ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY can scroll backwards

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cursor, resultset

I create a TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet

```
statement = connection.createStatement();  // TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY = default
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlCommand);
```

yet, when I do this

```
resultSet.afterLast();
while (resultSet.previous())
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-10s", resultSet.getObject(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I get the rows in reverse order, so it is definitely NOT forward only.
I expected a runtime-error, something like: "Cannot scroll backwards"

What is wrong in my assumption?

Comment: Looks like your JDBC implementation may ignore the suggested scroll direction

Comment: "Which JDBC driver"? for MySQl

static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/world";
DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,....)

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver defaults to a scrollable cursor, even if set to `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL JDBC driver defaults to a scrollable cursor.